# Finding out the missing value in dataframe based on a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a solution to find out the missing values based on column

for example :

```
Field_name                Field_Type     Field_Id
Message type identifier       M              0
Nan                           M              1
Bitmap secondary              C              1
Nan                           C              2
Processing code               M              3
Nan                           M              4
Amount-Settlement             C              5
```

So here I want to know the missing values in the column Field_name and the `Field_Type = 'M'`, Ignoring the missing values in `Field_Type = 'C'`

Expected Output :

```
Field_name   Field_Type  Field_Id
Nan                M    1
Nan                M    4
```

Edit : 
Can we do this for a list of dataframes ?

```
data_list = [df1,df2,df3]


output : result [[missngvalues in df1],[missngvalues in df2],[missngvalues in df3]]
```

Comment: You mean "Ignoring the missing values in Field_Type = 'C'" instead of "M"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `nan` are missing values chain mask [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) and [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for `==` by `&` for botwise `AND`:

```
df[df.Field_name.isna() & df.Field_Type.eq('M')]
```

If `nan` are strings compare both by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html):

```
df[df.Field_name.eq('Nan') & df.Field_Type.eq('M')]
```

---

```
print (df)

  Field_name Field_Type  Field_Id
1        Nan          M         1
5        Nan          M         4
```

EDIT:

If working with list of `DataFrame`s:

```
data_list = [df1,df2,df3]
result = [df[df.Field_name.isna() & df.Field_Type.eq('M')] for df in data_list]
```

Comment: I have edited the question a bit..can you please let me know how do it ?

Comment: @pylearner - Can you check edited answer? Not sure if first or second solution is necessary use, so change `df.Field_name.isna()` to `df.Field_name.eq('Nan')` if necessary

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61555519/extract-whole-row-out-where-there-is-maximum-value-based-on-other-column 
can you help me out in that question ?